# File carving software for Windows or Linux (pref windows). Need to rescue SMS from an Android userdata partition

Tags: android, data-recovery, sms

I lost some text messages, so I make a dd .img file of the userdata partition on my Android phone.

Does anyone know of file carving software in Windows or Linux that can handle an .img file of this type?

I was using scalpel, a Linux tool. I got it to carve some data, and might have been able to get further with it. However, for unrelated reasons I had to delete the Linux VM and start again.

When I reinstalled scalpel on the new Linux VM (same distro, same computer, same VMWare version, etc) scalpel just returned 'segmentation fault' and wouldn't work at all. I tried installing  the same version of Linux (latest Debian) on a spare hard drive, and I got the same fault.

So scalpel is out, unless someone knows why it would behave like that.

Tried a vast array of data recovery packages for Android: Mobisaver, Belkasoft Evidence Centre, and the like (will put up an exhaustive list later). I'm willing to pay a non-ridiculous price (say up to £50) for a product (or service) which can demonstrate the ability to return all my texts. Obviously don't want to pay speculatively.

Comment: Have you tried the obvious candidates: TestDisk and PhotoRec? Both available cross-platform for free.

Comment: I completely forgot about testdisk and assumed it wouldn't run on a non-physical disk. Having a go with that now, thanks. Will report back

Comment: Using disk images is even the recommended way to use it :) Good luck!

Comment: I couldn't get it back in the end, though testdisk found a lot of files and I think it's likely I would have been successful if I'd done this first, instead of panicking and installing a lot of useless software on the phone, which probably obliterated what I wanted to find. Ah well :/

Comment: Yepp, that's lesson #1 in such cases: immediately stop writing to the disk. You've learned it the hard way now, unfortunately. You might wish to write up an [answer to your own question](/help/self-answer), includung that warning.